# Combine 2 SQL queries into one query and convert to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I need to combine these two separate queries into one because it's not efficient AND have this converted to C# ASP.NET from Classic ASP

```
SQL = "SELECT MemID FROM network WHERE userid='"&strTemp&"'"
Set rsNet = Conn.Execute(SQL)
if NOT rsNet.eof then
strList = rsNet("memID")
end if
rsNet.close
set rsNet = Nothing

SQL = "SELECT Distinct userid, username, img1, birthday, gendid, city, state, country, title FROM UserInfo WHERE (userinfo.userid IN (" & strList & ")) "
Set rsView = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsView.Open SQL, Conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
if NOT rsView.EOF then
arrN = rsView.getrows()
end if
rsView.close
set rsview = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the C#, but the SQL goes to a classic join...

```
SELECT userid, username, img1, birthday, gendid, city, state, country, title
FROM UserInfo
JOIN network
ON network.MemID = userinfo.userid
AND network.userid = :inputUserId
```

You should only need the `DISTINCT` if for some reason you have non-unique rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dtTable = null;
using (SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
{
   string strQuery = @"SELECT Distinct userid, username, img1, birthday, gendid, city, state, country, title 
   FROM UserInfo 
   WHERE userinfo.userid IN 
   (
      SELECT MemID 
      FROM network
      WHERE userid= @userid 
    )";
   SqlDataAdapter oDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, oConn);
   oDataAdapter.Fill(dtTable, "TableName");

}
```

Comment: Good example - one small issue I see is @userid - it's not set anywhere in your code.  I think it would be better to do parameterized query as in my example.  Otherwise, you beat me to the punch (slow typing day for me).

Answer (score 0):

@X-Zero's select is good -- one thing is just that the parameter would be @uinputUserID, not :inputUserId, if you're using microsoft (sql-server).

Otherwise, converting this to asp.net (using c#) depends on what control you want to use -- dataset, datatable, datasource, datareader, etc...  @Mr.'s data table is a good way, but then you'll need to databind it to whatever control is using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I'm including the using statements in case your not familiar with the rights one to use for ADO.NET):

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient

public DataTable GetUserDetails(int userID)
{
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(<your connection string>))
    {

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userid", userID);
        cmd.Text = "SELECT DISTINCT u.userid, u.username, u.img1, u.birthday, u.genid, u.city, u.state, u.country, u.title FROM UserInfo u JOIN Network n ON u.userid = n.userid WHERE n.userid = ?";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);        

        da.Fill(dTable);
    }

    return dTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not as trivial as the other answers think, because it looks like `MemId` is a comma-delimited string field (bad database design). Therefore, you have to use dynamic SQL inside... dynamic SQL.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"ConnectionStringHere"))
{
    conn.Open();

    IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = @"
        DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)

        SET @sql = '
            SELECT DISTINCT
                userid, username, img1, birthday,
                            gendid, city, state, country, title 
                FROM UserInfo 
                WHERE UserId IN 
                (' + (SELECT MemID FROM network WHERE UserId = @userId) + ')'

        EXEC(@sql)";

    IDbDataParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
    param.DbType = DbType.String;
    param.Value = "12345"; // TODO
    param.ParameterName = "@userId";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    IDataReader dr = null;

    try
    {
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // TODO: Process result set
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dr != null)
            dr.Close();
    }
}
```